# Multiple definitions error with gcc

Tags: c++, gcc

I am getting strange multiple definition error in a project i am working under gcc. I browsed through all similar errors people complained on the forums yet i can not resolve the issue based on their workarounds. I am making a snake game under linux with ncurses library anways
i have a point.h which has

```
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

struct point
{
    int x,y;
    point();
    point(int col,int row);
};
point::point(){
    x=0;
    y=0;
}
point::point(int col,int row)
{
    y=col;
    x=row;
}
#endif
```

draw.h which only has methods to render snake with ncurses 
and snake.h

```
#ifndef SNAKE_H
#define SNAKE_H

#include "point.h"
#include "draw.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <deque>

class snake
{
 private:
  int maxwidth,maxheight;
  float delay,acceleration;
  int old_axis,direction,tailtime,tailcurrent;
  int limit_down,limit_right;
  std::deque<point> dsnake;
  std::deque<point> food;
   char blk,partchr;
 public:
  snake();
  void drawBorders();
  void drawSnake();
  void clearSnake();
  void start();
  void moveSnake(int towards);
  void moveSnake();
  void play();
  void TailAdd();
  point getmovePoint(point pos,int axis);
  void getDirection();
  void generateFood();
  void drawFood();
};
#endif
```

yet i get error when i compile with
i tried it with lots of different g++ flags. Tried making the point class instead of a struct and defined the declerations in a cpp file, but they don't unfortunately work.
The project works only if i include "snake.cpp" in main.cpp which is not really a sane solution
i guess.

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp snake.cpp -lncurses
/tmp/ccCSPcUp.o: In function `point::point()':
snake.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `point::point()'
/tmp/cc1BDIIH.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccCSPcUp.o: In function `point::point()':
snake.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `point::point()'
/tmp/cc1BDIIH.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccCSPcUp.o: In function `point::point(int, int)':
snake.cpp:(.text+0x20): multiple definition of `point::point(int, int)'
/tmp/cc1BDIIH.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x20): first defined here
/tmp/ccCSPcUp.o: In function `point::point(int, int)':
snake.cpp:(.text+0x20): multiple definition of `point::point(int, int)'
/tmp/cc1BDIIH.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x20): first defined here
/tmp/ccCSPcUp.o: In function `init()':
snake.cpp:(.text+0x43): multiple definition of `init()'
/tmp/cc1BDIIH.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x43): first defined here
/tmp/ccCSPcUp.o: In function `getMax(bool)':
snake.cpp:(.text+0x85): multiple definition of `getMax(bool)'
/tmp/cc1BDIIH.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x85): first defined here
/tmp/ccCSPcUp.o: In function `drawColumn(int, char)':
snake.cpp:(.text+0xe8): multiple definition of `drawColumn(int, char)'
/tmp/cc1BDIIH.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xe8): first defined here
/tmp/ccCSPcUp.o: In function `drawLine(int, char)':
snake.cpp:(.text+0x140): multiple definition of `drawLine(int, char)'
/tmp/cc1BDIIH.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x140): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

> and here are rest of my files.
>
> http://pastie.org/private/gpzbuohvlxhzyz5z4vjsw draw.h
>   http://pastie.org/private/pfvriwssdzwreab5ibyww main.cpp
>   http://pastie.org/private/ehkyvcodge7w1wqwpsbw point.h
>   http://pastie.org/private/eomqodk9di3tj1ramyfg snake.cpp
>   http://pastie.org/private/wznpkpayh9iopvjnrdfjw snake.h

Comment: What's your compiler and linker command actually?

Comment: You're defining functions in header files. Don't do that, it causes this error. Define them in `.cpp` files.

Comment: tried using "g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp snake.cpp -lncurses" and some other variations.

Comment: You can also use member initialization list like `point::point(int col,int row) : x(row), y(col) { }`

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect to have in a header:

```
point::point(){
    x=0;
    y=0;
}
```

If the same function is included in two different units then this function body is defined twice, violating the One Definition Rule.

A function body may only have at most one non-inline definition in the whole program. Multiple inline definitions are permitted so long as they are exactly identical.  (In both cases, each translation unit can still only have at most one definition).

To fix this, either:

- Define the function in-line in the class definition
- Move the function to a .cpp file

Same goes for the other constructor.

Comment: unfortunately i also tried moving these functions to a point.cpp file yet it did not solve my problem. And how can i make these functions inline? Constructor of the struct

Comment: example of inline is having `point() { x = 0; y = 0; }` in the class definition.  If you have moved those functions to point.cpp and still get the problem then update your post to show that version of the code (and make sure you are compiling exactly what you posted)

Comment: Also try and post a **minimal** example; e.g. `float delay,acceleration;` has nothing at all to do with your problem and could be removed. same goes for most of what you posted.

Comment: @photonist look closely at your error messages. The same problem is given for several other functions as well as the `point` constructors. After you made the change I suggested , read your error messages again and see if they are different (e.g. they no longer give error for the `point` constructors).

Comment: I tried that again it didn't resolve the issue however,making all these functions inline during decleration solved it. Why is that?

Comment: And i am sorry, next time if i ever post i will post minimal as posssible. After working on same issue more than 3hours i got a little fuzzy minded i think. Apologies

Comment: @photonist my post explains why making them inline solve it. (If moving the functions to cpp file didn't solve it then either you didn't move them properly, or you're #including cpp files, or something else bizarre like that)

Comment: So snake includes draw, main includes snake, and if i do not make it inline(because cpp file didn't solve it) translation units for snake and main will have their own copies of draw. Am i right?

Comment: You should never have a cpp file include another cpp file.

Comment: umm but main includes snake.h and snake.h has the function definitions inside snake.cpp, is that wrong?

Comment: @photonist `.cpp` files should include `.h` files.  `.h` files may include other `.h` files.   You shouldn't have function bodies inside `.h`. files other than inline definitions or templates.